# Is it possible to set an image for push notification from www/img folder for an IONIC app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to set an image for push notification for my IONIC app. For that I am using phonegap-plugin-push plugin and following code:

```
var pushConfig = { 
       android: {
              senderID: "XXXXXXXX",
              icon : "icon_push"
       },
       ios: {
              alert: "true", 
              badge: "true", 
              sound: "true"
       }
};
```

For that I need to set icon_push.png images in drawable folder manually as per the size available in this link.

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_image55

Can I put icon_push.png in www/img folder directly and use into my code directly without manually putting all images in drawable folder? If yes, what will be the code for that?

Answer (score -1):

Ionic is cool enough to provide a [dedicated tool](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) to generate icons (and splashscreens) in all required formats.

Following the docs:

> Save an `icon.png`, `icon.psd` or `icon.ai` file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project. The icon image’s minimum dimensions should be `192x192 px`, and should have no rounded corners. Note that each platform will apply it’s own mask and effects to the icons. For example, iOS will automatically apply it’s custom rounded corners, so the source file should not already come with rounded corners. This Photoshop icon template provides the recommended size and guidelines of the artwork’s safe zone.

Then just run:

```
$ ionic resources --icon
```

The icon will be automatically picked up for your push notifications in the right size, depending on the device.

Comment: This is not what the user asked. App icon is what you are answering. What the user wants is to set a specific icon specified in the push notification request. You might have multiple icons for different push notifications (not the app icon).

As far as I know there is a way to do this since ios10 but the process seems very manual and complex (objective-c/swift). I wasn't able to find a higher level solution. I'm interested on it, let me know if somebody has this.

Comment: In the question it was not specified that the icon should be different from the app icon. The answer I've provided geenrates icon that is used both as app icon and as a default for notifications generated for app.